# Will new operator return NULL?

Tags: c++, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will new return NULL in any case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550451/will-new-return-null-in-any-case)

Say i have a class Car and i create an object

```
Car *newcar  = new Car();
if(newcar==NULL) //is it valid to check for NULL if new runs out of memory
{
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

On a standards-conforming C++ implementation, no.  The ordinary form of `new` will never return `NULL`; if allocation fails, a `std::bad_alloc` exception will be thrown (the `new (nothrow)` form does not throw exceptions, and will return `NULL` if allocation fails).

On some older C++ compilers (especially those that were released before the language was standardized) or in situations where exceptions are explicitly disabled (for example, perhaps some compilers for embedded systems), `new` may return `NULL` on failure.  Compilers that do this do not conform to the C++ standard.

Comment: Exactly! The way to do it in C++ is with try/catch blocks. Here is an example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/bad_alloc/

Answer (score 13):

No, `new` throws `std::bad_alloc` on allocation failure. Use [`new(std::nothrow) Car`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/nothrow/) instead if you don't want exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

By default C++ throws a std::bad_alloc exception when the new operator fails. Therefore the check for NULL is not needed unless you explicitly disabled exception usage.

Comment: ... and if you disable exception usage, then the language is no longer C++.