# Feature, bug or UB? The expected infinite loop in my code is deleted when using gcc -O2

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, g++, undefined-behavior

The code is the following:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using u64 = std::uint64_t;

u64 *test() {
    u64 *a, *p;

    p = (u64 *)&a;
    a = (u64 *)&p;

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            p = new u64((u64)p);
        }
    }

    while (true) {
        if ((u64)p == 0) {
            break;
        }

        p = (u64 *)*p;
    }

    return p;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << test() << std::endl;
}
```

And the compiled asm of function test is the following:

```
test():
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

You can see https://godbolt.org/z/8eTd8WMzG.

In fact, it's expected when the final stmt is `return a;` although the compiler tells a warning about retuning a local address. And if I make `a` and `p` being global variables, everything is ok, see https://godbolt.org/z/n7YWzGvd5.

So, I think that maybe I face some ubs so that its behavior not match my expectation?

Comment: That much UB all in one place, who knows what the compiler'll do with it.

Comment: I am sad the compiler discarded a perfectly good memory leak factory.

Answer (score 3):

The instructions `p = (u64 *)&a;` and `a = (u64 *)&p;` followed by assignments and the dereferencing of the variables **break the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)** resulting in a *undefined behaviour*. Indeed, `p` and `a` are of type `u64*` while `&a` and `&p` are of type `u64**`. Moreover, `p = (u64 *)*p;` is a perfect example of instruction breaking the strict aliasing rule: `u64**`, `u64*` and `u64` are three distinct different types.

If you want to solve this, you first need to check the size and the alignment of the types match (it *should* be fine on a mainstream 64-bit architecture). Moreover, you should use a `std::bit_cast` or a `memcpy` to perform the conversions (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67636231/what-is-the-modern-correct-way-to-do-type-punning-in-c/67636420#67636420) related post).

Moreover, note that infinite loops *without side-effects* are [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) too. Since `p` [cannot be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389420/will-new-operator-return-null) in your case. A compiler detecting that your loop is infinite and does not have any side effect can just remove it (or can generate a wrong code too).

Comment: Thanks! But how does `p = (u64 *)*p;` break the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: `p` is dereferenced to (simultaneously) read/store values of different types like `u64`, `u64*` (and `u64**`). See the [definition on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:T._Canens/strict_aliasing_rewrite). Such type are not *similar* because they are not the same type "*after stripping away cv-qualifications at every level*". This case is clearly an "*attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType*".

Comment: Note that the strict aliasing rule does not strictly apply to one specifically statement but rather to the entire code. If this is still not clear to you, you can focus on the type of the objects actually read/stored at the dereferenced address: what is the one used to store the object and what is the one used to read it? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68863124) post may also help you to understand strict aliasing.