# new never fails?

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

In C++, we usually see and write code like,

```
Sample sample=new Sample();
if ( sample == NULL )
{
     std::cout<<"Memory allocation failed" << std::endl;
}
```

But in C#, I *rarely* see this: (at least I've never seen this)

```
Sample sample = new Sample();
if ( sample == null )
{
     Console.WriteLine("Memory allocation failed\n");
}
```

Means, in C#, we rarely **check** if a `new` failed or not. Why is it so? Does it have something to do with *"In C#, new never fails"*?  Is there such a thing in C# that `new` never fails?

If it fails, then why such "check" is so rare in C#? I'm **not** talking about `OutOfMemoryException`, that is after all *exception*, not "check". I'm talking about the coding style.

Comment: "In C++, we usually see and write code like..." No we dont. A standards-conforming C++ implementation is required to indicate errors in `new` by throwing a `std::bad_alloc` exception. Some older C++ compilers returned a null pointer on error in `new`, but this is not the case anymore nowadays.

Comment: A conforming new in C++ will never return a null pointer.  If you "usually see and write code like" this, you're Doing It Wrong™.  (You need the std::nothrow placement form of new to get a null pointer returned.)

Answer (score 15):

According to msdn

> If the new operator fails to allocate memory, it throws the exception OutOfMemoryException.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

By the way, only old C++ compilers return 0 when they  trying to allocate memory. Modern ones throwing std::bad_alloc exception. If you wish old behavior you need to write

```
Sample sample=new(std::nothrow) Sample();
```

Comment: not on all compilers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550451/will-new-return-null-in-any-case

Comment: @rve I say modern compilers. VC++ 6 is not a modern compiler.

Answer (score 12):

In C#, `new` throws an `OutOfMemoryException` if it fails, so a `NULL` check is not necessary.

Incidentally, the same applies in C++ as well - `new` throws `std::bad_alloc` if it fails, so there really is no need to test against `NULL` in C++ either.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, unlike `malloc`, `new` doesn't return `NULL` on failure. In fact, it throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception on failure.

If you want `new` to return `NULL` on failure, you have to explicitly tell it not to throw an exception. Use `std::nothrow` version for that purpose. (header file : `<new>`)

Comment: On certain non compliant compilers new can return NULL.

Comment: @rve : On conformant implementation `new` would never return `NULL` unless the `std::nothrow` version of `new`  is used.

Answer (score 5):

If [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newoperator) fails, then there will be an `OutOfMemoryException` thrown.

So the equivalent of the C++ code you have would be this:

```
try { 
  Sample sample = new Sample();
} catch(OutOfMemoryException e) {
  Console.WriteLine("Memory allocation failed\n");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Sample sample=new Sample();
if ( sample == NULL )
{
     // You will never get here!
     std::cout<<"Memory allocation failed" << std::endl;
}
```

We don't write this in C++ either. `"Memory allocation failed"` will never appear. In both languages you get an exception if the allocation fails. In C++ it's `std::bad_alloc`, in C# it's `OutOfMemoryException`.

Answer (score 1):

new can certainly fail.

Constructors are allowed to throw exceptions. 
You can also run out of memory when creating a new object.

Answer (score 1):

There are an OutOfMemoryException in C#

Answer (score 1):

1. I rarely see it in C++
2. It doesn't make sense in C#, because it simply will just throw an Exception

Answer (score 1):

In C++ new can return NULL when using a non compliant compiler (see [Will new return NULL in any case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550451/will-new-return-null-in-any-case))

But, the proper way in C++ is that `new` throws an exception when out of memory, just like C#.

The check for NULL is only needed on certain compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Is this some test code you wrote? If so, I assume that you don't actually keep the reference to the object you created, meaning that the garbage collection will kick in and delete some of the objects you created previously.

That said, you can certainly run out of memory if you allocate enough memory and do keep references to it (at which point an exception will be thrown - a NULL pointer as a return value for memory allocations is more common in C, and in C++ versions written for video game consoles.)