# C++ calling to (vector)pointer from another class return empty size

Tags: c++, vector, sdl

Im trying to make a SDL mini game and I have a problem when I try to call to a vector pointer from another class. The problem is that when I call to the function the result is a empty vector.

In this class I call to drawBoss every frame

```
class badBoss {
public:

    struct fire {
        int type, x, y;
        float v, vx, vy;
        int angle;
    };
    std::vector<fire> vFire;
    std::vector<fire> *pvFire = &vFire;


    void drawBoss(SDL_Renderer *ren) {
        vFire.push_back(fire({0,cP1.x+20,cP1.y,cP1.w,cP1.h,v}));
    }
```

};

In this class I try to capture vFire pointer but the size is always 0.

```
class colision {


public:
    badBoss _boss;

    void detectColision() {

        std::vector<badBoss::fire> lala = *_boss.pvFire;
        std::cout << lala.size() << std::endl;

    }
```

};

this is the main of my game

```
int main() {
  colision _colision;
  bool aktibo = true;

    while(aktibo) {

      _badBoss.drawBoss(ren);
      _colision.detectColision();       

    }

    return 0;
}
```

How can I get correctly the value of pointer?

EDIT: Thanks to your suggestions, I could fix it. This was the problem: 
In the colision class I was doing a new instance on badBoss, and of course, when a call to vFire vector was always 0.

Now I call to colision from the main fuction with the correct instance like parametre and....wallaaa!! all runs perfect!

Comment: why do you have the vector and a pointer to the vector as public member variables? Did you try to access the vector by accessing the vector directly in `detectCollision()` ?

Comment: A possible scenario is that the `badBoss` instance you're accessing in `_boss.pvFire` isn't the same as the one you call `drawBoss` on.

Comment: hi @tobi303, im new in C++. I have the two variables like public because I want to access them from other class. And I try too access them directly from collision class but is not the same variable. Its always empty

Comment: Hi @molbdnilo that's the question. How can I get the same variable of the badBoss class.

thanks for the answers guys!!

Comment: @ErikBasañez You need to pass the instance of `badboss` to the given `collision` instance. Can you show the definition and initialization of the `_boss` field in `collision`?

Comment: try to use `vFire` directly instead of the pointer. It might be that during instantiation of the `badBoss` the `vFire` is assigned a new vector which would make the pointer rather pointless (not sure if there is more code you dont show)

Comment: @ErikBasañez And now show the code which calls `drawBoss` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@molbdnilo has a good point. you should add a constructor (or a setter) in colision class which initializes the _boss object. i.e.

```
colision(badBoss boss) {
 _boss = boss;
}
```

Comment: Hi @asif !!

BINGO!! that was the problem!!! In the colision class I was initialization a new instead of badBoss and, of course, vFire always was 0. 

Thank for all!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, it is a matter of vector pointer initialisation:

```
class badBoss {
public:

    struct fire {
        int type, x, y;
        float v, vx, vy;
        int angle;
    };
    std::vector<fire> *vFire = new std::vector<fire>();
    // I don't think it's even needed
    //std::vector<fire> *pvFire = &vFire;


    void drawBoss(SDL_Renderer *ren) {
        // Isn't one value missing?
        vFire->push_back(fire({0,cP1.x+20,cP1.y,cP1.w,cP1.h,v}));
    }
};
```

And now, for the Data collision

```
class collision {

public:
    void detectCollision() {
        std::cout << _boss.vFire->size() << std::endl;

    }
};
```

Hope this helps!
Reference:
[Pointer to a Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946217/pointer-to-a-vector)

Comment: thanks for the answer @Alfonso. Your code runs perfectly but I have the same problem. If I make std::cout <<vFire->size() << std::endl; in the drawBoss function, all is good but If I make std::cout << _boss.vFire->size() << std::endl; in detectCollision the size of the vector is empty. 

(If you want, I have the full code in github)

Comment: Sure, can I have the link to check for the whole code?

Comment: Take it easy Alfonso, its only a hobby. Is not a my work ;-)
https://github.com/perikobermio/xfighter.git

Comment: You should almost never need pointers to standard containers.