# Base operand of '->' has non-pointer type vector<object*>

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

```
std::vector<Piece*> player1, player2;

/* Filling player 1 and 2 vith piece 
   player1.push_back(new Piece()) */

std::vector<Piece*> *currentPlayer, *opponent;

currentPlayer = &player1;
opponent      = &player2

for(int i = 0; i < currentPlayer.size(); ++i)
{
    // This is where i get the error
    // error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::vector<Piece*>'
    currentPlayer[i]->memberFunctionOfPiece()
}
```

As you can see I am trying to use a pointer pointing to a vector of pointers. but getting non-pointer type when trying to access the vector
Why can't i access the member function?

Comment: I am certain there's a duplicate for it, but I can't for the life of me, to find an exact duplicate. But, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946217/pointer-to-a-vector .

Comment: `currentPlayer[i]` "works" because of pointer arithmetic. You need `(*currentPlayer)[i]`. And the condition in the for loop would fail; you need `for(int i = 0; i < currentPlayer->size(); ++i)`

Comment: Life would be much easier if you stop using pointers

Comment: this code has to be wrong: `currentPlayer.size()` is invalid. Part of your code wants currentplayer to be a vector, other parts want to be a pointer to a vector. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use square brackets on a pointer type:

```
currentPlayer[i]->memberFunctionOfPiece();
```

you can use operator[] or even better use the at function

```
currentPlayer->at(i)->memberFunctionOfPiece();
```

or

```
currentPlayer->operator[](i)->memberFunctionOfPiece();
```

Comment: or `(*currentPlayer)[i]->memberFunctionOfPiece();`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ranged for loop on STL containers

```
for(auto&& player : *currentPlayer)
{
    player->memberFunctionOfPiece();
}
```