# operator new with empty exception-specification calling constructor when allocation returns 0

Tags: c++, g++, standards, new-operator

I have the following declaration:

```
void * operator new (size_t s, PersistentMemory * m) throw()
   {return m->allocatePersistentMemory(s);}
```

I'm testing memory exhaustion on start-up, which results in `m->allocatePersistentMemory(s);` returning 0.  New then calls the constructor with a null pointer for `this`

However, based on 3.7.3.1 paragraph 3 of C++ 2003 standard:

> An allocation function that fails to allocate storage can invoke the
>   currently installed new_handler (18.4.2.2), if any. [Note: A
>   program-supplied allocation function can obtain the address of the
>   currently installed new_handler using the set_new_handler function
>   (18.4.2.3). ] If an allocation function declared with an empty
>   exception-specification (15.4), throw(), fails to allocate storage, it
>   shall return a null pointer. Any other allocation function that fails
>   to allocate storage shall only indicate failure by throwing an
>   exception of class std::bad_alloc (18.4.2.1) or a class derived from
>   std::bad_alloc.

The way I understand things is that having `m->allocatePersistentMemory(s)` return null should result in the whole `operator new() throw()` returning null without calling the constructor.  Am I missing some other condition elsewhere that overrides this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are not calling the `new` you think you are calling.

[This works as you expect.](http://ideone.com/Go3G3)

```
void *myalloc (size_t) { return 0; }
void * operator new (size_t s) throw() { return myalloc(s); }
struct Foo {
    std::string s;
    Foo () { std::cout << this << std::endl; }
};
int main () {
    Foo *f = new Foo;
    if (f == 0) std::cout << "f is NULL" << std::endl;
}
```

Where as, [this fails.](http://ideone.com/2loA4)

```
void *myalloc (size_t) { return 0; }
void * operator new (size_t s) throw() { return myalloc(s); }
struct Foo {
    std::string s;
    Foo () { std::cout << this << std::endl; }
    void * operator new (size_t s) { return myalloc(s); }
};
int main () {
    Foo *f = new Foo;
    if (f == 0) std::cout << "f is NULL" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is declared as part of a macro that incorporates a specialized definition of operator new into each class definition, so in this case there is no global `operator new (size_t s, PersistentMemory * m) throw();`.  Thanks though :)

Comment: @shroudednight: Still might be a different `new` operator being called though. Placement `new`, or `new[]` should also be checked.

Comment: Thanks for that extra push, you were right.  The macro I expected to be defined for this class wasn't in use and instead had its own custom version.

Comment: @user315052 : why both runs well on VS2010?

Answer (score 2):

Section 5.3.4 (13) of the C++03 standard says:

> [*Note*: unless an allocation function is declared with an empty
>   *exception-specification* (15.4), `throw()`, it indicates failure to
>   allocate storage by throwing a *bad_alloc* exception (clause 15,
>   18.4.2.1); it returns a non-null pointer otherwise. If the allocation function is declared with an empty *exception-specification*, `throw()`,
>   it returns null to indicate failure to allocate storage and a non-null
>   pointer otherwise. ] If the allocation function returns null,
>   initialization shall not be done, the deallocation function shall not
>   be called, and the value of the *new-expression* shall be null.

The phrase "initialization shall not be done" implies that the constructor will not be called.

Interestingly -- and unless I am reading the spec wrong -- when your allocation function specifies `throw()` and returns null, the value of the invocation of "new" itself is null.  I had always thought this was impossible (see, for example, pretty much every answer at [Will new return NULL in any case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550451/)).

Comment: Thanks for the additional reference.  The environment I work in is exception and standard library phobic, instead using jump buffers (setjmp) ¬.¬ which aren't available at this point, so I had significant incentive to find a work around that wasn't replacing everything with separate allocations, tests, and placement news.