# Constructor call when operator new failed

Tags: c++, gcc, c++03

I’m trying to implement a technique to test failing operator `new` described in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6108/Simulating-Memory-Allocation-Failure-for-Unit-Test.

This is a sample code being tested:

```
VArray* arr = new VArray(1U, 3U, true);
```

I can make `new` return `NULL` instead of allocating memory. In this case, the program should continue to next line (which should test if `arr == NULL`) and this is exactly what it does in MSVC.

However, the constructor of `VArray` is still called after the failed `new` in GCC. And since `this` is `NULL`, it results in SIGSEGV on the first assignment to a property. This seems to be a wrong behavior according to C++03 standard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514528/711006

My implementation of operators `new` and `delete` follows.

```
unsigned int OperatorPlainNewFailsAfter = UINT_MAX;

void* operator new(const size_t _size) throw()
{
  void* result;
  if(OperatorPlainNewFailsAfter == 0U)
  {
    result = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    result = malloc(_size);
    OperatorPlainNewFailsAfter--;
  }
  return result;
}

void operator delete(void* _memory) throw()
{
  free(_memory);
}
```

What do I miss?

Comment: A replacement `operator new` must throw `std::bad_alloc` on failure. Returning `NULL` is a violation of contract. "Required behavior: Return a non-null pointer to suitably aligned storage (3.7.4), or else throw a `bad_alloc` exception. **This requirement is binding on a replacement version of this function**."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard requires that an allocation function (e.g. the basic `operator new`) fails by throwing a `std::bad_alloc` exception, if it fails. It's not allowed to return a nullpointer. When you do return a nullpointer you have **Undefined Behavior**, and yes, one possible consequence is that a constructor is called.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but my original intention was to replace `new (std::nothrow)` and I agree I’ve done it half-way. So you helped me to finish it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If the `operator new` being called is declared `throw()`, then
it is an error for the compiler to not check for a null pointer.
But it is illegal to declare a non-placement new `throw()`, so
there's no point in the compiler checking it; if anything, it
should complain when it sees the declaration, because the
non-placement `operator new` is implicitly declared.

If you want to test for failing `new` (and it's a good idea),
your `operator new` function shouldn't return a null pointer,
but should throw `std::bad_alloc`.  Otherwise, you're not
testing the same thing.  On the page you site, the test code
uses a placement new instead.  The code is still illegal,
because his `operator new` may return a null pointer without
having declared the function `throw()`, but that is easily
fixed.  (Or not.  He calls `::operator new`, rather than
`malloc`, for the actual allocation, and this function *may*
throw.  He also calls the `::operator new` function to allocate,
but used the `::delete` operator de free; if you call
`::operator new` to allocate, you should call `::operator
delete` to free.)  Of course, even fixed, it doesn't test
anything useful, since what you need to know is that your
program reacts correctly to `std::bad_alloc`, not that it
reacts correctly to a null pointer that it will never see.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough check of the original example. Yes, I modified it because placement `new` isn’t the thing I want to test. Since I’m replacing the “basic” global `new`, I cannot call `::operator new`, since it gets replaced! That’s the reason for `malloc` and `free`.