# Code after function fails to execute - c++

Tags: c++, runtime-error, execution, skip

I am trying to write a program to simulate Huffman encoding and decoding. In order to do so, I needed to serialize a binary tree in a text file, so that I could read it again later and reconstruct the tree (when decoding the huffman file).

However, after my function (readBinaryTree) that reads the file (which is recursive), the program just stops executing. I've never seen this before.

Here's the code:

```
if (!decode) {
    .
    .
    .
    //alot of stuff here
    .
    .
    .
 }


else if (decode) {
    std::ifstream keyFile("hufftreekey.txt");

    Node* HuffTree = NULL;

     std::cout << "PRE!" << std::endl;

    readBinaryTree(HuffTree, keyFile);  //THIS FUNCTION EXECUTES, BUT NOTHING AFTER IT DOES

     std::cout << "POST!" << std::endl;


    std::map<char, std::string> codes = buildCodes(HuffTree);

    std::ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open ("mobydick_decoded.txt.huff");

    char c;
    std::ifstream input( argv[ 1 ] );
    while (input >> std::noskipws >> c) {
        if (codes.find(c) != codes.end()) { 
            std::string huffcode = codes[c];
            outFile << huffcode;
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "ERROR!" << std::endl;
        }

    }
    outFile.close();

}
```

Output in terminal is "PRE!", but it never prints "POST!". I don't get any error message, no exceptions are thrown, it just never prints, and nothing after the function is called is executed.

This is the function:

```
 void readBinaryTree(Node* root, std::ifstream &fin){
 std::string s_val;
 char val;
 std::getline(fin, s_val);
 val = s_val[0];
 if(val == '#')
     return;
 else if(val == '_') {
    root = new Node();
    if (root == NULL) {
        std::cout << "MEMORY ALLOC FAILURE!" << std::endl;
     }
    root->content = '_';
    readBinaryTree(root->leftChild, fin);
    readBinaryTree(root->rightChild, fin);

 }
 else {
     root = new Node();
     if (root == NULL) {
        std::cout << "MEMORY ALLOC FAILURE!" << std::endl;
     }
     root->content = val;
     readBinaryTree(root->leftChild, fin);
     readBinaryTree(root->rightChild, fin);
 }
```

}

This is not an infinite loop problem, the program finishes but it just seems to skip everything after the readBinaryTree function is called

Comment: What platform are you on? Does it just hang, or does the program simply exit?

Comment: I'm compiling with g++ on cygwin on Windows 8.1. It doesn't hang at all, just simply exits as if it has completed

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with how cygwin handles various conditions. I would guess that the process is getting killed due to some problem, like exceeding your stack space, etc.

Comment: if that was the case, wouldn't memory allocation via "new" fail and create a NULL pointer? I've modified the code to check for a null pointer after allocation but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Stack space is different from heap, though. Anyway, I just don't know enough about cygwin. Run with Visual Studio or Linux if you can.

Comment: @compscimaster: For a standard conformant  implementation allocation failure for the way you use `new` [never returns a nullptr, but instead throws a `std::bad_alloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550451/will-new-return-null-in-any-case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not building a binary tree. You're leaking memory like a sieve leaks rain-water, then executing *undefined behavior* to add insult to injury.

Change this:

```
void readBinaryTree(Node* root, std::ifstream &fin)
```

to this:

```
void readBinaryTree(Node*& root, std::ifstream &fin)

// see addition here ====^
```

Try passing that pointer by *reference* (or address) and see what happens.

Comment: Thank's for the advice, I fixed the code. However, I ran it in linux and it seems with gdb and it seems like I'm getting a seg fault at the end of the function. Getting this error message: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_int_malloc (av=0x7ffff78b9760 <main_arena>, bytes=40) at malloc.c:3302
3302 malloc.c: No such file or directory."

Comment: @compscimaster that would be an entirely different issue, related to the fact that with the above change you're actually *retaining* all that data you're allocating. I had a feeling fixing the code above would unfold other problems in the code. At this point you should turn Valgrind lose on your code, not just gdb. And carefully mind-walk the code paths for possible flaws. I can take another look at it for something obvious, but isn't a forum for online-interactive debugging. At least this part is fixed.

Comment: @compscimaster and note: **all** constructors for `Node` should *all* be initially setting the `leftChild` and `rightChild` members to null. Ideally you make a constructor that actually takes the `content` as a parameter. It will simply your code as well as reduce the chances of an invalid pointer usage later.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, if new fails, it will NOT made the assigned pointer NULL. It will throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception. My guess is that `root = new Node();` failed and an exception was raised but no catch was found by C++(Recall `try{...}Catch{...}` in C++ for exception handling).  According to C++ standard, all uncaught exception will cause the program terminates immediately. Thus "PRE!" was printed but "POST!" was not. If you really want to use `if(ROOT == NULL)` to check whether dynamic memory allocation is successful, please use placement new like:

```
root = new (nothrow) node();
```

nothrow descriptor ensures that new will NOT throw an exception and will always return NULL if it fails.

I hope my explanation helps.

Comment: @compscimaaster: Also, note that on Linux with g++, it will print out uncaught exception. I don't know what it does on cygwin.