# Could a 'new' statement fail without throwing an exception?

Tags: c++, new-operator

Consider the following code snippet:

```
try{
LibObject* obj = new LibObject();
if (!obj)
    return 0;
}catch(...){
    return 0;
}
return 1;
```

I don't know the implementation of the LibObject since it comes from an external library.

Generally speaking, could have any sense to check if the new object instance (obj) is NULL? Or the check is simply unuseful?

Could a new statement return a NULL object without throwing an exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will new return NULL in any case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550451/will-new-return-null-in-any-case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LibObject* obj = new LibObject();
```

Don't use parenthesis here. And if you don't want alloc exception, you should use std::nothrow

```
LibObject* obj = new(std::nothrow) LibObject;
if (obj == nullptr) return 0;
else return 1;
```

This is the correct syntax. You can find a reference here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/nothrow/

Comment: What if the exceptions are disabled?

Comment: @user1095108 If you disable the exception, new will return null_ptr instead

Comment: So you really need to use that syntax for every new statement in your code? I've never seen it before, maybe because memory allocation it's being trusted...

Comment: @ABCplus it's a example. I would use a new without try/catch (and let abort the program if i don't have enough memory).