# why to avoid check for null after new as per ISO C++

Tags: c++, memory, null

ISO C++ says...

```
Fred * p = new Fred();  // No need to check if p is null
```

No need to check p for null why is that so ?

Comment: Its explained @ source: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#new-never-returns-null

Comment: `new` can only return `nullptr` if you have `new (std::nothrow) Fred()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550451/will-new-return-null-in-any-case

Answer (score 12):

The reason is that this type of call to `new` results in an exception being raised if there is a memory allocation error. So there is no situation in which `new` would return `NULL`/`nullptr` when invoked like this.

It you want `new` to return `NULL` instead of throwing an exception, you can invoke it with `std::nothrow`:

```
Fred* p = new (std::nothrow) Fred();
```

Here, it would make sense to check against `NULL`/`nullptr`.