# Why does GCC 11.1 warn about "use of possibly-NULL 'operator new(32)' where non-null expected"?

Tags: c++, gcc, new-operator, static-analysis, null-pointer

I am using GCC 11.1 and I have enabled the static analyzer with the option `-fanalyzer`. Now in this line:

```
    std::pair<NodeIterator, bool> result = idNodeMap.emplace(id,
            new Node(id, point));
```

I get the following warning:

```
..\src\Mesh\Mesh.cpp: In member function 'void Ct::Geometry::Mesh::addNode(int, const gp_Pnt&)':
..\src\Mesh\Mesh.cpp:30:43: warning: use of possibly-NULL 'operator new(32)' where non-null expected [CWE-690] [-Wanalyzer-possible-null-argument]
   30 |                         new Node(id, point));
      |                                           ^
  'void Ct::Geometry::Mesh::addNode(int, const gp_Pnt&)': events 1-2
    |
    |
In file included from ..\src\Mesh\Mesh.h:12,
                 from ..\src\Mesh\Mesh.cpp:9:
..\src\Mesh\Node.h:31:9: note: argument 'this' of 'Ct::Geometry::Node::Node(int, const gp_Pnt&)' must be non-null
   31 |         Node(int id, const gp_Pnt& point);
      |         ^~~~
```

Have I understood the warning correctly, that GCC wants me to check whether `new` returns `null`? According to this post: [Will new return NULL in any case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550451/will-new-return-null-in-any-case) this is never the case with current compilers and sound compilation options. So is this a warning for rare special cases and I should disable it?

Or have I overlooked something and there is a real danger in my code?

Comment: Do you have an overrriden `new`?

Comment: @HattedRooster No.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the analyzer. The constructor won't even execute if allocation fails, so the note is extra strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is GCC bug [#94355](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94355).

Some work has been done, but the issue is still open and there's a [comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94355#c7) in there with this specific issue.

It sounds like it doesn't yet differentiate `operator new` that throws `std::bad_alloc` on allocation failure from (a hypothetical) one that returns `nullptr`.